# How can I fix - src/pages/Leaflet/osm-providers.js Line 1:1: Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default import/no-anonymous-de

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

export default {

maptiler: {
url:"https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=fXmTwJM642uPLZiwzhA1",

attribution:'© [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/) © [OpenStreetMap](http://osm.org/copyright) contributors',

```
},
```

}

please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

the linter asks you to name the object before exporting it, that way if you search for it through your code you'll find it.

```
const map = {

maptiler: { url:"https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=fXmTwJM642uPLZiwzhA1",

attribution:'© MapTiler © OpenStreetMap contributors',

},
}

export default map
```

https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md